# MediaMetadata to MediaStore.Audio.Media

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, mediastore

I'm using MediaController.Callback to get notified on each new metadata.
I want to use the metadata to fetch the album art of the metadata.
Here is what metadata contains:

> Bundle{ android.media.metadata.ALBUM_ART =>
>   android.graphics.Bitmap@18869e33; android.media.metadata.ARTIST =>
>   Thousand Foot Krutch; android.media.metadata.DURATION => 187899;
>   android.media.metadata.USER_RATING => Rating:style=2 rating=unrated;
>   android.media.metadata.ALBUM => Welcome To The Masquerade;
>   android.media.metadata.TITLE => Fire It Up;
>   android.media.metadata.ALBUM_ARTIST => Thousand Foot Krutch; }

As you can see, the metadata contains the album art. However, I don't need the album art on the callback, but on the Activity, so I cannot use this.

The album art path is stored on MediaStore.Audio.Media's ContentReslover.

How do I convert a MediaMetadata to Audio's ID for MediaStore.Audio.Media

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was to search the title in the `MediaStore.Audio.Media` to get the song data:

```
getContentResolver().query(MediaUri, new int[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID},
                MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE + "=" + DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString(title), null, null)
```